# Where is the Git dot (.) current directory pathspec documented?

Tags: git

From both my past experience and current Internet research, the `.` in Git commands such as `git add .` appears to be a [`pathspec`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) which matches the current directory.  However, I'm not seeing this defined in the official git documentation at [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs).

The `pathspec` documentation says:

> The pathspec syntax is as follows:
>
> - any path matches itself
> - the pathspec up to the last slash represents a directory prefix. The scope of that pathspec is limited to that subtree.
> - the rest of the pathspec is a pattern for the remainder of the pathname. Paths relative to the directory prefix will be matched against that pattern using fnmatch(3); in particular, ***** and **?** can match directory separators.

Following these rules tells me that `.` is probably matched by `fnmatch(3)`.  According to [man7.org](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), `fnmatch(3)` checks whether the string argument matches the pattern argument, per `glob(7)`:

> The fnmatch() function checks whether the string argument matches
> the pattern argument, which is a shell wildcard pattern (see
> glob(7)).

The [`glob(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) documentation defines a number of special wildcard characters, but does not seem to have any special support for `.`.

> A string is a wildcard pattern if it contains one of the
> characters '?', '*', or '['.

What am I missing here?  Why does `.` match all files in the current directory, and where is this documented?

Comment: `.` _is_ the current directory. It's not a wildcard. You can see it with  `ls -a`.

Comment: `.` is the current directory, so it falls into the first category: *any path matches itself*.

Comment: `.` and `..` are part of the standard paths, they have nothing to do with fnmatch or glob. Any system call dealing wth paths (`open()` or `stat()` for example) understands `"."`  as "the process' current working directory".

Comment: Depending on the file system, `.` is probably just a regular file-system entry, not anything that's special to any system call.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell (bash, zsh, csh, etc.) recognizes `.` as the current working directory (and `..` for the parent of the current working directory). Git is just using what the shell passes it.

Comment: Why does the shell matter?

Comment: the difference between `.` and `*` is that `.` is not expanded by the shell. `.` is part of the standard of the system

Comment: Not shell — filesystem driver(s) in the OS kernel.